# SUM() elapsed time in sql with text data type

Tags: php, mysql, database, time, sum

I'm trying to SUM() my Elapsed column in an SQL query, but the datatype for my Elapsed column in the SQL database is text, and I am unable to change it. My attempt is below, but I continue to receive "failure".

```
<?php require 'dbcon.php'; ?>
$elapsed = "SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `STR_TO_DATE(Elapsed,'%d,%m,%Y') ) ) ) FROM Picks";
$s = $con->prepare($elapsed);
//$s->bind_param();
$s->execute();
$results = $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($results){
    foreach($results as $result){
        foreach($result as $val){
            echo $val;
        }   
    }
}
else {
    echo "failure";
}
```

THe Elapsed column in the SQL database looks like this-[Datatype as display in a datatable table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCbqG.png)

If there is more information I forgot that would be helpful, don't hesitate to ask. Thanks!

Comment: what's the backtick doing in ``...`STR_TO...``? if you were outputting something OTHER than a fixed/useless error message, like `$con->errorInfo`, you'd have been told about that.

Comment: I removed the backtick and now I don't receive anything, just a blank screen. I no longer see the failure message. Thoughts?

Comment: basic debugging: check if the prepare succeeded, check if the execute succeeded. check if there were actually any rows return (if there's none, then $results is an empty array and your foreach does nothing).

Comment: @Marc B I just added an `echo "success";` line right after the end bracket of the first foreach loop and before the if ending bracket, and I see success

Comment: `var_dump($results)` and see what came out of the db, then.

Comment: This is what came out when I put var_dump($results) at the bottom of the page-   successarray(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( STR_TO_DATE(Elapsed,'%d,%m,%Y') ) ) )"]=> NULL } }

Comment: so there you go. you got one row of data, with a null value, which means one of those time functions failed and returned a null, which infected the rest of there results. sql nulls will print as a zero-length/invisible string in php. I'll bet a shiny penny it's the str_to_date() function

Comment: So that means my actual SQL query is wrong correct?

Comment: maybe. it executed, so it's syntactically correct now. but that doesn't mean it's a PROPER query. e.g. `select * from foo where 1 = 0` is correct, but it's not exactly proper. you need to check which part of that time function call chain failed.

Comment: Ok thank you I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're getting a `NULL` value from your query. The issue is in your STR_TO_DATE declaration; you're using

`STR_TO_DATE(Elapsed,'%d,%m,%Y')`

These look for [day month and year values.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) Try using `%H,%i,%s`, which look for hours minutes and seconds, which is how your Elapsed column is formatted according to your picture.

Comment: It worked thank you! <- just kidding I was editing a commented section and I'm an idiot

Comment: Happy to help! Remember to error check as Kyle Scheer mentioned in his comments. Once you are able to determine if it's a php syntax error or just a bad query it becomes much easier to solve.

Comment: It's still returning null

Comment: Hmm. Now I would break your query up to test each individual section of it and find where it breaks. If you have access to phpmyadmin or something similar I'd recommend using its SQL query box to help here.

So first try simply grabbing anything to make sure you're accessing your server correctly: 

`SELECT * FROM picks`

Comment: Then try editing your Elapsed value with STR_TO_DATE() and see if it returns an actual date format. Then try using TIME_TO_SEC and SEC_TO_TIME and make sure they work. I'm not at my dev station so I'm unable to test for you